# How to use subfolder with controller in codeigneter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a controller inside a folder but I'm getting this error

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
folder
```

**controller/admin
            -Test.php**

**here is controller**

```
<?php 

class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
    echo 'hello';
}
function hello() {
    echo 'world';
}
}
?>
```

**here is route**

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/test';
```

Comment: Check if you're getting something with index.php in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

**Route:**

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/test/index';
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
    function hello() {
        echo 'world';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is not work

Comment: in your config file where there is `$config['index_page'] = ''` is blank or not?

Comment: this is blank i have remove with .htaccess

Comment: And also change `Test.php` to `test.php` controller file.

Comment: sir not working

Comment: @ChandraKumar Do not advice something that is just opposite to [framework standard](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming).

Comment: this is not my questions ,how to access controller inside folder